# Is there a good argument to buying the more-expensive overclocked version of a particular video/graphics card?

Tags: graphics-cards

There's a video card that I want to buy (Asus ROG STRIX 1080 GTX) that comes as a regular version (A8G, which I believe is already overclocked compared to the default OEM specs) and an overclocked version 08G. I believe both ship with an easy to use overclocking software program.

The latter is actually only slightly more expensive in terms of MSRP. However, because of the lack of availability, it tends to be much more expensive than the A8G version.

Is there a reason to pay the premium for the 08G or is the A8G expected to reach the same frequencies after manual overclocking without any further drawbacks?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a request for a hardware recommendation, and is not within our scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not expected to reach the same frequencies, though for most overclockers it is close enough that a significant price difference is not warranted.

In silicon chip manufacturing there is a process called *binning*, wherein tests at the factory sort chips according to the quality of their manufacture. The highest quality chips - the highest "binned" examples - are the ones which will respond most positively to overclocking, because they don't skirt the QA lines on any of their specifications. Those chips are usually not simply thrown back in with the rest of the batch and sold so that some customers get lucky with OCing and others don't - the higher binned chips are used to create the higher-tier SKUs, and within those SKUs, the best of the best are used to create the OEM overclocked models. Those chips are the ones which stand the best possible chance of being monstrously good overclockers - the only pitfall some people fall into is in thinking that the factory overclock indicates the percentage by which they will beat more conventional SKUs - this not an accurate way of thinking, because sometimes OEMs are able to set factory OCs very close to the upper limit of the part's capability.

The last thing to consider is that the OC'd models of GPU often receive some of the best addons an OEM can offer - better caps, better software, backplates, and better cooling solutions. All of that combines to add value to the more expensive models. In some cases, you can see crazy things like OC'd R9 270s outperforming R9 270Xs as a result of this.

The thing to keep in mind when all is said and done, however is this: are you the type of person to worry over your GPU's clockspeed for several weeks, tweaking it and testing it meticulously until you have achieved the best possible result? If not, it probably makes more sense to go for the similar but cheaper model. Factory OCs on their own usually do not offer a sufficient value increase to justify the premiums they are sold at.

I recommend the slower, cheaper version of the card unless you are very passionate about overclocking.

Comment: In my particular case, the clock of the overclocked version is 6% faster than the non-OC version at 1.5% higher MSRP, but because of the lack of availability is currently about 20-30% above the cost of the non-OC version on the market. Pretty sure they are otherwise the same, however.

Comment: Yeah the market is really just not in your favor there.